# Consume Workday's SOAP API

Tags: java, api, soap, workday-api

I'm new to SOAP API and also to Workday. I'm searching which API do I have to use to create a Worker object.

I already found under IntelliJ how to build Java objects from WSDL files and how to manipulate them.

Compared to REST API, I find SOAP and Workday's documentation really tough.

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 0):

The Hire_Employee and Contract_Contingent_Worker webservice operations are used to create Workers - Employee and Contingent Worker respectively.  Both are available in the Staffing webservices.

How you use those will depend on what information about the worker is already in the system as, for example, an Applicant or a Former Worker.  It will also depend on the requirements for the Supervisory Organization and Position into which the worker is being hired/contracted.

It will help you significantly to first get used to performing the hire/contract process in the Workday user interface.  These webservices are driving the same business processes launched from the UI and so come with the same requirements for data.

Comment: Thanks ! If I understand well my need (which is use the API to provision user to Workday from Okta) Hire_Employee would be the webservice I need.
Because it's the first time I'm using Workay, I think it would be necessary that I fully understand how this solution works first.

Comment: Provisioning between Okta and Workday normally works the other way.  I believe that Okta provide an integration which finds new employees in Workday and then creates them in Okta.  Going the other way is likely to require information that you may well not have in Okta.  If this is the case, then at best you are likely to need to make additional webservice calls to look up that information in Workday, at worst it may not be possible with capturing more data in Okta.